# Icon to Signify "search products" or "products"

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I'm trying to design a search box for products searching and I can't seem to think of how to represent search for products. My client wants his website to look like this http://www.hipmunk.com/. I'm just following his orders and now I'm trying to think of an icon to represent products. I'd be glad to hear any suggestions from you all! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the good old magnifier is going to top your list. You may be able to add another graphic (say a box or whatever closely represents your the product) with it but the magnifier is probably your best bet? I say this not because everyone else uses it on their sites, but because everyone who visit their sites universally understand that it (the magnifier) is a search of some sort (which is why it's used as much as it is). Hope that made sense.

You of course don't have to follow that trend, I'm just considering UX.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm gonna do as you said but I'm still open to more suggestions. :)